# Getting an image as base64 and writing as JPG

Tags: c++, c++11

I can receive the base64 correctly, but i can't save the image correctly, it gets corrupted.

And I open the file jpg create and he not presents all the string converted

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> 
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <vector>


    //g++ -std=c++11 -static main.cpp -o test.exe
    //./-Server.run 50007


    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    #define SERVER_PORT htons(50007)

    static const char* B64chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    static const int B64index[256] =
    {
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  62, 63, 62, 62, 63,
        52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 0,  0,  0,  0,  63,
        0,  26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
        41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51
    };

    const std::string b64encode(const void* data, const size_t &len)
    {
        std::string result((len + 2) / 3 * 4, '=');
        char *p = (char*) data, *str = &result[0];
        size_t j = 0, pad = len % 3;
        const size_t last = len - pad;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < last; i += 3)
        {
            int n = int(p[i]) << 16 | int(p[i + 1]) << 8 | p[i + 2];
            str[j++] = B64chars[n >> 18];
            str[j++] = B64chars[n >> 12 & 0x3F];
            str[j++] = B64chars[n >> 6 & 0x3F];
            str[j++] = B64chars[n & 0x3F];
        }
        if (pad)  /// set padding
        {
            int n = --pad ? int(p[last]) << 8 | p[last + 1] : p[last];
            str[j++] = B64chars[pad ? n >> 10 & 0x3F : n >> 2];
            str[j++] = B64chars[pad ? n >> 4 & 0x03F : n << 4 & 0x3F];
            str[j++] = pad ? B64chars[n << 2 & 0x3F] : '=';
        }
        return result;
    }

    const std::string b64decode(const void* data, const size_t &len)
    {
        if (len == 0) return "";

        unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*) data;
        size_t j = 0,
            pad1 = len % 4 || p[len - 1] == '=',
            pad2 = pad1 && (len % 4 > 2 || p[len - 2] != '=');
        const size_t last = (len - pad1) / 4 << 2;
        std::string result(last / 4 * 3 + pad1 + pad2, '\0');
        unsigned char *str = (unsigned char*) &result[0];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < last; i += 4)
        {
            int n = B64index[p[i]] << 18 | B64index[p[i + 1]] << 12 | B64index[p[i + 2]] << 6 | B64index[p[i + 3]];
            str[j++] = n >> 16;
            str[j++] = n >> 8 & 0xFF;
            str[j++] = n & 0xFF;
        }
        if (pad1)
        {
            int n = B64index[p[last]] << 18 | B64index[p[last + 1]] << 12;
            str[j++] = n >> 16;
            if (pad2)
            {
                n |= B64index[p[last + 2]] << 6;
                str[j++] = n >> 8 & 0xFF;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    std::string b64encode(const std::string& str)
    {
        return b64encode(str.c_str(), str.size());
    }

    std::string b64decode(const std::string& str64)
    {
        return b64decode(str64.c_str(), str64.size());
    }
    int main() {

        char buffer[20883];

        int serverSock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        sockaddr_in serverAddr;
        serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddr.sin_port = SERVER_PORT;
        serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        bind(serverSock, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

        listen(serverSock,1);

        sockaddr_in clientAddr;
        socklen_t sin_size=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        int clientSock=accept(serverSock,(struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, (socklen_t*)&sin_size);


            bzero(buffer, 20883); // Zerando o buffer

            FILE *output;    
            output = fopen("test.jpg", "w");    
            unsigned int readBytes = 0;  
            string decoded_string;


            int rec = recv(clientSock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            cout << (buffer) << endl; 
            decoded_string = b64decode(buffer);  
            cout << decoded_string << endl;

            fwrite(&decoded_string, sizeof(char), sizeof(decoded_string), output);


            //vector<uchar> data(decoded_string.begin(), decoded_string.end());
            //fwrite(&data, sizeof(data), readBytes, output);

            fclose( output ); 

        return 0;
        close(serverSock);
    }
```

```
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
    ����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 82
    ��C         
    !'"#%%%),($+!$%$��C         $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$��h�"��

    ���}!1AQa"q2��#B��R��$3br�  
    �G�GE���v���g������Kٽ�iq@��q�q]<6��.=�:�0`c�Z���`z�t{iAW�[=r*e�����q�ջ&+nP����iM�qz����`0�oH�E|���x'^�U��hdc���}S|w"��⾃��{�
                                                                   ���#�)rHr��3�޷v��P��7Uq����W��L��9G���{lm?���c�w�q�yM�1��z�����&D���V���q�i�fy���1�Y�����J4&�S������I�Ӆ0pQ֤�70QL�ٌ�8��JM���VH����sSX�1�)���(2)���"��@����������������^Z�Gʸ�^�������������������������������������
    ��"�<WW                                        ?����Q�Q�AF3N�P��R⍴iq�1K�)     r-�>����
    Z`��)q�1�i�R��"Ih��9�p^���/����u�p}�?A^l��B���Zt��x�����O>���|;裠�"�t9�I�`�q�J�*��O���Q�c"����=  M"�i1�CFi�T�E5��NZh�ހ�)q����@������֘���fy���-�.��0�9�ft�_c_N����HX�YZu��E\{��@<WDZH�I�T���Y:���X�uU|Aw� �A��*[I�&(H��CQ���m ��  �s^T��;�f���/��nf�����~�5Ȥ;ߖ��k��4A$Fh݃����B1[��5VXF9��h����?�%FȘlu 8�~����~R��J�5>Г�gz��J�2�F?�fx����7�`O�uxq�O��Ѹ��4���n����>�ꓻ9k��"�$BM6H&�NM)���(�E�F�������T�z�����x�Mx�Cz�I�)�=t���N��E�&�P)phFi�MS�(�M�e�2Ǔ�CK�4� ��zS�0�z��)A��p��p�N��✦�8-�5wNM��RQZ:y��qӟ����eCsN�� ��[L�H�z�����}��(�ʱǏ��皃��yڊ��9��k�Ӵ9��$���9���?�k���Q�I��U�?(��y�u.4$�H�k���wn<�����=4���H7��t�炧�`R0��WT�s[?�Xp�4��:��ZhE���x����3�W���}��\p[�oQ�z�}Ep�/��4�b�c�r�؃��]G��Gc�E��Tg��M�P�iE�p��9{�?����#ӂ�q��I1&Jq�ޕ���������ܹl�9o�O�ҿh'f�]c����#K�x��9eS��zP���wդ�o�����.�Hn�7�A")fhSo+�������8]cM{
                                                    �:��Gj���v���ԓۧ-ks��G��Lt��|+ԓQk���P�����x�=��լ�����K�\�g��2W�����8�x���X��@O\I���V����H���KY�G�n�=�\����j��%�y�|��z˸�FФL+SM+@���L+Sm��ϭ""�jGZaa���HG4�
    p��p4�������)�pk&��7Z��$E[�.|���1�����<sߦ=k�A[VrJ���F��%�g�����>e��p�`��u�2I������k�����FX�Qx���VZ'����H������vS�
    îq��\�����Euae��                             �LWt�&q���l��l5%�m�
    J��?�F�5 9�B�Z�`߼0���fkWG������|!�b���a8��Z�
                                        Ғ���x^2���t��S��Y��~����    ����o�A���B�]�pk���?�i�����巩�RZ��7!��׬xrr�~n+�4w�fS�צh`9�P����Uc��(�P���ȷf�^8�,��F2Յ�nT�+;v�,� �����a˭���5�$Q��k��B��F��9�A Ec��[ַ���8��?��*Vf�����5�����v֣�2:{U���qQ_\��u��g��y�.>���R��F'=��p�httT���N�v�SI�H��\2��Cx�ݓ��V���v�'�|�\
    �/C<R\�!�(�N��L��P�q��rw2�db1��x��%>�W���_�z����+��ȿ�[8�<��3��l4��É��(�ң#��X�M�i�
    `0�i��i�@
             ja�ژz�4x5j�O�%�* i�@2en�"��pqR@�����|��$�8�9���+��=��k�+@��#d���ʛG�Y�z``Z�>"�WK�c�;X��vk���-��.6�qﴲ����|J���#�����g�~��
     ...
        ��G��(��n1���;߭I+R����EWP8����v������>�H��a�-H�����]$��D�Ъ(����Ͽ�hڕ�~�����!y����}��仹�����B�&�(��i��E��
```

Comment: Is the socket really a relevant part here? Can you successfully encode and then immediately decode data?

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```cpp
output = fopen("test.jpg", "w");
```

The second parameter of fopen is the "open mode". "r" for read, "w", for write, etc... By default files are opened in text mode, this causes newline characters to be handled in a weird way sometimes, so you should be opening the file in binary mode. Changing that line of code to this, should made it work:

```cpp
output = fopen("test.jpg", "wb");
```

As a general rule, always open files in binary mode if they're not text files.

Comment: Or even if they are. Text mode is a crime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it was that way before. I just changed a few things to see if it worked and forgot to fix it. But really this is wrong rs